# converting a row of data.frame to column names using data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a large data frame of 5 million rows, with three columns.  I would like to transform it to a matrix which has as its rows USER_ID, ID as columns, and value as CNT. This could be done with `melt` and `cast` or

```
xtabs(CNT ~ USER_ID + ID, data = foo)
```

however the object created is to large and I get a following error `'dim' specifies too large an array`

```
USER_ID ID CNT
1      1.813e+14 21   1
2      1.559e+14 28   1
6      1.592e+14 71   2
```

I'm trying to use data.table as is seams to handle large data much better then data.frame, but I can't figure out how to use data.table to create a contingency table I want.
Does any one have any idea how to get this working? I'm also thinking of creating and empty matrix with appropriate dimensions and fill it with appropriate indexes.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  It is not clear what's your starting point and what is your ending point.  The small table you posted is which?  Also, please try pasting the output of `dput(head(<yourdata>))`

Answer (score 3):

Try this using the built in data.frame `CO2` :

```
> xtabs(uptake ~ Treatment + Type, CO2)
            Type
Treatment    Quebec Mississippi
  nonchilled  742.0       545.0
  chilled     666.8       332.1
```

or similarly using `tapply`:

```
> with(CO2, tapply(uptake, list(Treatment, Type), sum))
           Quebec Mississippi
nonchilled  742.0       545.0
chilled     666.8       332.1
```

and now compare to data.table:

```
> library(data.table)
>
> DT <- data.table(CO2)
> DT[, as.list(tapply(uptake, Type, sum)), by = Treatment]
    Treatment Quebec Mississippi
1: nonchilled  742.0       545.0
2:    chilled  666.8       332.1
```

*Cautionary Note:*   If the same levels of `Type` do not appear in every `Treatment` group then this would not be sufficient.  In that case it would be necessary to convert `Type` to be a factor in the data table (as it already is in `CO2`).

ADDED:

Its actually possible to get rid of `tapply` and have a pure data table approach like this:

```
> DT[, setNames(as.list(.SD[,list(uptake = sum(uptake)), by = Type][, uptake]), 
+   levels(Type)), by = Treatment]
    Treatment Quebec Mississippi
1: nonchilled  742.0       545.0
2:    chilled  666.8       332.1
```

The cautionary note above applies here too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach (also using `CO2` dataset):

```
dt = data.table(CO2)
dt[, sum(uptake), by = list(Treatment, Type)][,
     setNames(as.list(V1), paste(Type)), by = Treatment]
#    Treatment Quebec Mississippi
#1: nonchilled  742.0       545.0
#2:    chilled  666.8       332.1
```